# How to determine storage type (SSD drive or HHD .mechanical drive), using C language

Tags: c, windows, linux, solid-state-drive

How can I, from a C program, read the hardware information of a drive? (I.e. to determine if the drive is an SSD or a mechanical disk.)

Comment: What do you mean by "character"? The drive letter?

Comment: @Tim: I guess he meant if SSD has drive letter 'D' and normal HDD is drive letter 'E', how can he check which drive is using which drive letter via "C". Pun not intended. :P

Comment: i think from vista onwards it would always make the boot drive C. i'm pretty sure i had dual boot and BOTH windows OSes thought their primary drive was C. please clarify question!

Comment: i think he means 'how can i determine the drive technology when iterating through the drives on my system'

Comment: I don't think SSD versus traditional is something you can easily check.  You might be able to learn something from the model numbers, but that's hit or miss unless you've got exact model numbers to check for.

Comment: OT but, "i think from vista onwards it would always make the boot drive C" -- no, usually yes but not always, it depends on how you do the install. "dual boot and BOTH windows OSes thought their primary drive was C" -- sure, usually yes but not always.

Comment: What specific information do you want to know about each drive?

Comment: Yea. I wanto know which one is ssd drive, or whether there is no ssd

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908188/is-there-any-way-of-detecting-if-a-drive-is-a-ssd), so you may want to check there for more information. There's some code there to determine the rotational latency of the drive, which I have not tried myself.

Comment: Interesting that there seems to be no reliable way in Windows to detect this.

Answer (score 17):

SSD are supposed to identify themselves as non-rotative. For linux, as example, you can get the info via sysfs:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
```

If it returns 0, you have SSD...

Comment: If I could give this a thousand upvotes, I would. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Not reliable. Some drives lie on this value now. Also, what about hybrid drives that are both HDD and SSD?

Comment: Well, @volomike, I think that is beyond the question asked. He specifically said SDD or HDD. If the driver responses otherwise, that is the manufacturer issue and nobody, not even Linus Tornvalds, can help you with it (except that Linus could complain about it publicly and have some impact)...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing a read/write test to try to determine capabilities ?

Comment: NO, when my app is installed, i will check all the drives, if there is one SSD, it's running another way...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [GetDriveType](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32GetDriveType.htm) Method from the win32 library, and you might be able to differentiate that way, or you use GetVolumeInformation to try and determine it from the label.

Comment: 'coz my app maybe run on any host, i dont know what the label will be...so i think guessing label is suitable

Comment: That function does not report if a drive is SSD or not.

Answer (score -2):

This guess is a long shot but I can't find anything better. In the device's identification structure, see if it supports acoustic management. Old disk drives didn't, but maybe most modern disk drives do. Obviously SSDs don't need acoustic management but let's hope they'll say they don't, instead of pretending to be disk drives.

Comment: This isn't going to work.  Seagate has dropped acoustic management from their modern conventional drives.