# How to detect SSD in Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, solid-state-drive, iokit

Is there a reliable, quick, deterministic way (i.e. *not* a benchmark) to check whether the system drive Mac OS X is on is a Solid State Drive?

Is there any other indicator how well disk handles parallel access? I'm trying to adjust number of threads that my program is going to use for disk-bound operations.

I'm not interested in raw speed or seek time, only which type of access – serial or parallel – is faster for the drive.  I don't expect users of my program to use iSCSI or RAID. SSD is my focus, anything else is nice-to-have.

`Device Characteristics` of `IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice` contains this information. How can I read it programmatically?

---

So far I've figured out it goes like this: (following is pseudocode)

```
match = IOBSDNameMatching(kIOMasterPortDefault,0,"disk0s2");
IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, match, &iterator);
while(entry = IOIteratorNext(iterator)) {
   do {
     entry = IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry(nextMedia, kIOServicePlane, &entry);
     dict = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(nextMedia, 
            CFSTR(kIOPropertyDeviceCharacteristicsKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
     [dict objectForKey:CFSTR(kIOPropertyMediumTypeKey)];
   } 
   while(!dict && entry); 
}
```

---

Edit: [Here's complete source code](https://github.com/kornelski/itunesfixer/blob/master/SSD.m). I've verified it works with Intel SSD and OCZ Vertex.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/908188/545127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to get that kind of information, you're best guess is IOKit.

You can try some of it's functionality using the *ioreg* command line tool or the *IORegistryExplorer*.

---

Here's some code that might help you. It fetches all hard drives that aren't a RAID and aren't partitions. This isn't what you want, but it might get you started.

```
#import "TWDevice.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <paths.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/IOBSD.h>
#include <IOKit/storage/IOMedia.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/Kext/KextManager.h>


@implementation TWDevice

@synthesize name, devicePath, size, blockSize, writable, icon;

+ (NSArray *)allDevices {
    // create matching dictionary
    CFMutableDictionaryRef classesToMatch;
    classesToMatch = IOServiceMatching(kIOMediaClass);
    if (classesToMatch == NULL) {
        [NSException raise:@"TWError" format:@"Classes to match could not be created"];
    }

    // get iterator of matching services
    io_iterator_t mediaIterator;
    kern_return_t kernResult;
    kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                                                      classesToMatch,
                                                                      &mediaIterator);

    if (kernResult != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        [NSException raise:@"TWError" format:@"Matching services did not succed."];
    }

    // iterate over all found medias
    io_object_t nextMedia;
    NSMutableArray *detectedDevices = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (nextMedia = IOIteratorNext(mediaIterator)) {
        NSMutableDictionary *properties;
        kernResult = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(nextMedia,
                                                                                  (CFMutableDictionaryRef *)&properties,
                                                                                  kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

        if (kernResult != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            [NSException raise:@"TWError" format:@"Getting properties threw error."];
        }

        // is it a whole device or just a partition?
        if ([[properties valueForKey:@"Whole"] boolValue] &&
            ![[properties valueForKey:@"RAID"] boolValue]) {
            TWDevice *device = [[[TWDevice alloc] init] autorelease];

            device.devicePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%sr%@", _PATH_DEV, [properties valueForKey:@"BSD Name"]];
            device.blockSize = [[properties valueForKey:@"Preferred Block Size"] unsignedLongLongValue];
            device.writable = [[properties valueForKey:@"Writable"] boolValue];
            device.size = [[properties valueForKey:@"Size"] unsignedLongLongValue];

            io_name_t name;
            IORegistryEntryGetName(nextMedia, name);
            device.name = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            …

            [detectedDevices addObject:device];
        }

        // tidy up
        IOObjectRelease(nextMedia);
        CFRelease(properties);
    }
    IOObjectRelease(mediaIterator);

    return detectedDevices;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful. Without it I'd be fruitlessly poking IOKit C++ API.

Comment: @porneL: It looks like you've figured it out on your own. I suppose you don't need any more help on this question, is this right?

Comment: Yes, I've got it figured out now. The code I've added to the question seems to work (It'll need some extra work to support File Vault, but I can get it from there - IOKit registry is no longer a mystery to me.)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I think you should go the benchmarking route, because it more accurately answers your question - you don't *really* care that the disk happens to be an SSD, you just care that the disk is really fast. What if the user is using a fast RAID setup, or a Fiber Channel array, or is using iSCSI?

Just read a bunch of random sectors from the underlying /dev/diskX and if it meets your requirements you can treat it as a "Fast" drive

Comment: I don't have any baseline measurement of "fast". I would have to run two benchmarks and compare. Time spent for reliable benchmarking could be longer than time saved by choosing better strategy. Short benchmark is going to be unreliable, and it's tricky to take caches, latency, etc. into account. 

I'm looking for fast, deterministic solution. Doesn't need to support anything but SSD.

Comment: Fair enough but I will tell you this, that this is the approach that the Windows OS takes - if you see a bit of statistics, it'll be very easy to see; run 2 tests, one with a backwards sequential read (i.e. sector 5,4,3,2, etc), then a 2nd with a random sector read. If the variance is basically the same, you've got an SSD; on mechanical disks they'll be wildly different

Answer (score 3):

This only seems possible for internal drives. I could not find a way using IOKit to query a Samsung T5 external USB 3 SSD for its SSD-ness (nor a Toshiba Canvio USB HDDD). I did manage for the internal drive in my MBP, though.

Disk utility also doesn’t think the Samsung is an SSD, so that makes me think there may not be a way, other than to measure actual performance.

Answer (score 0):

The number of threads? 1 is going to overwhelm any disk, SSD, RAID or not. Disk is slow, processor is fast. The OS is going to reorder your disk requests anyhow (or at least it should) to get the least head movements.

Comment: At least on Windows and Linux, the OS will not reorder disk requests for SSDs

Comment: In my experience OS X doesn't do good job managing disk access (parallel access causes trashing rather than more efficient access). Multiple I/O-bound threads accessing SSD are faster - maybe just because there's some CPU overhead involved, but are faster nevertheless.