# Java Test disk is SSD or HDD

Tags: java, file, filesystems, solid-state-drive

I searched a lot about it but i don't found anything.
I have a file from `File f = File.getRoots().get(0);` and i would test if this drive is an SSD or an HDD.

Is this possible?
Here is some pseudocode that you can see what i need it for:

```
File f = myFile.getRoot();
if(isSSD(f)){
     System.out("We will write to SSD are you sure?");
}
```

If someone knows how to write the `public static isSSD(File f)` method please help.

I know there is NO cross platform solution so i think i need one for linux mac and windows:

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")){
    //The code for Win
}else if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("UNIX")){
    //The code for linux
}else if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")){
    //The code for mac
}
```

Gratefull for Answers.

Comment: This is most likely OS dependent. Do you need a cross platform solution?

Comment: no it must not be cross platform.

Comment: What OS are you targeting then?

Comment: i can use:
`if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")){
     //Do the windows check
}`

Comment: and the same for linux and mac

Answer (score 2):

There are ways for each OS, but not in native Java, so it will probably require some time to adapt to Java (JNI calls etc.). For example:

- Linux: [Is there any way of detecting if a drive is a SSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/908188/829571)
- Windows: [Detecting SSD in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23363115/829571)
- OSX:[How to detect SSD in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081941/829571)

Alternatively, you could run a benchmark and check if sequential reads and random reads have similar performance (SSD) or not (HDD). You will need to take caching into account etc.