# Detect SSD using Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way of detecting if a drive is a SSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908188/is-there-any-way-of-detecting-if-a-drive-is-a-ssd)

I'm interested in a method of detecting if a drive is SSD or not, please note that detecting "RPM 0" or "CompactFlash" is not what I'm looking for.

I'm interested in a standard or future proof method for Windows 7.

**Additional info**: some drives are hybrid(SSD+HDD) -- they provide more storage at high speed by using the SSD part for caching -- this means that the RPM checking can easily fail, because windows can "read" the SSD or HDD part of the whole, in some cases both[!]

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't really future proof when it comes to hardware. Somebody might invent something in the future that you would like to treat the same way as a today's SSD, but it isn't an SSD. Or they invent a new type of SSD that you should treat differently but don't because it's still an SSD. What decision are you going to make based on this detection?

Comment: People used to write detection code like this for stuff like [Zip drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_drive). Hardware changes more quickly than software.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's more like a personal curiosity, I'm interested to know if it can be achieved by reading some flag/registry setting, etc. without actually benchmarking the disk...

Comment: @RRUZ that is almost 3 years old, many things have changed since then, my understanding is that some drives will make windows 7 automatically turn off the indexing service, so windows know somehow that a drive is SSD or HDD

Comment: @DorinDuminica A far I know that Windows 7 disables the indexing service and set the defrag to off on sdd drives because are detected as Non-rotating Media.

Comment: @RRUZ non rotating and maybe high capacity(say 40GB+)?

Comment: @DorinDuminica maybe you can add more factors like the size, but I think which the way to go is the `Rotation Rate`.